# Showing images from DB in aspx file issue regarding security

Tags: asp.net, exception, .net-security

we have link and when some one click on link then a image will be shown. the link is like

image.aspx will fetch image from db based on ID. whenever we click on link then a error is showing regarding security at staging server. locally everything works fine.

the security error we got when we click on like is

**Exception detail** 
  System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

**Exception url is**  http://206.72.115.172/catalogue/Image.aspx?DetailedProduct=1817&ColumnName=Picture1&Thumb=true

i just do not understand why it happen when we run the page from staging server but locally it works fine. i looking for solution. if anyone knows then please share with me.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

It look to me that you have some problems with the `<trust level>`.

> The error message indicates that your website doesn't have proper
>   rights on server.
>
> It seems that your host server uses Medium trust level to restrict
>   which resource types your application can access and which privileged
>   operations it can perform.
>
> During development in local, the code access security is Full trust
>   level and application can implement more works. For testing, you can
>   run your website with Medium trust level in local. I think we will get
>   the same issue.

```
 <system.web>
 <trust level="Medium" />
 </system.web>
```

> For the error "This configuration section cannot be used at this path.
>   This happens when the site administrator has locked access to this
>   section using  from an inherited
>   configuration file.", it means your host server has locked trust
>   section and we cannot modify it in application level web.config.
>
> It would be better you contact your host to confirm this or find
>   another host server that can support Full trust level with
>   application.

See more information [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1458917.aspx/1)

Comment: This should help me to get started http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.allowpartiallytrustedcallersattribute.aspx ?

Comment: Yeah this be a help as well. Or you can always test to set the trust level to full in you web.config and see if the error is still there. Otherwise you have to follow my link and see the talk about machine.config